# WPF Second Animation (StoryBoard) doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf

This is the scenario:
I Have a `Grid` and an `Button`. the Grid have a `Show` Boolean property. When user click on button, if `Show=false` then Grid become `Visible`. and when `Show=true` Grid become `Collapse`.
when it's visibility change, I do an animation for grid's `Height` with `StoryBoard`.
OK. every thing is fine. when user click the button, `Grid` appearing with animation. but when click again, the animation doesn't show and just Collapse occurred.
This is my code:

```
Storyboard growUpStory = new Storyboard();
    Storyboard growDownStory = new Storyboard();

    DoubleAnimation growUp, growDown;
```

In any method:

```
    height = Container.DesiredSize.Height;
    growUp = new DoubleAnimation
                {
                    From = 0,
                    To = height > MaxHeight ? MaxHeight : height,
                    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
                    AutoReverse = false
                };
               
                Container.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

                growDown = new DoubleAnimation
                {
                    From = height > MaxHeight ? MaxHeight : height,
                    To = 0,
                    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
                    AutoReverse = false
                };

                growUpStory.Children.Add(growUp);
                growDownStory.Children.Add(growDown);
```

and when I invoke the event:

```
if (Show)
            {
                Storyboard.SetTarget(growUpStory, Container);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growUpStory, new PropertyPath(Grid.HeightProperty));
                growUpStory.Begin();

                Container.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                Storyboard.SetTarget(growDownStory, Container);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growDownStory, new PropertyPath(Grid.HeightProperty));
                growDownStory.Begin();
                Container.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
```

I Try many ways but was unable to resolve. Where is my problem? have you any idea? thanks.

- I Can't use `XAML` here

Comment: I think that issue is here: ``From = height > MaxHeight ? MaxHeight : height`` try setting it to:  ``From = MaxHeight`` or ``From = Height``

Comment: @Tofik there is no different. I check it's value and it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animations are asynchronous, which means you are collapsing the Visibility at the same time that you are starting the "growDownStory" animation.

Add some delay, based on how long you expect your "growDownStory" animation to run.

Example:

```
    growDownStory.Begin();
    await Task.Delay(1000); // allow time for the animation to perform its visual
    Container.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Comment: The main issue is that you mention. the Asynchronous behavior and change visibility at same time. but delay doesn't resolve my problem. I just remove the Visibility command. Cause I should not doing change height and change visibility at same time and before the animation done, the grid was collapsed. Your answer is right. thank you.